# Alerts 129:20:1 and 129:12:2 and finding information on snort rules

Tags: snort

I am new to Snort and am using it to investigate the detectability of a given malware. I was writing my first custom rules and tested them. During that process I additionally received the following two alerts:

`[129:20:1] TCP session without 3-way handshake [**] [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP}`

`[129:12:2] Consecutive TCP small segments exceeding threshold [**] [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP}`

I wasn't able to locate the files in which these alerts are defined and couldn't find helpful information on the internet either. I stumbled upon the snort-sigs archives which are concerningly confusing and unhelpful. Can someone tell me what triggers the two presented alerts or where I could find useful information?

Answer (score 1):

in snort.conf go to line 273 (default conf) check for: preprocessor stream5_global: track_tcp yes
just change it the yes into no, that should remove the Consecutive TCP small segments exceeding threshold alert on log.
sorry bad english

Comment: The question wasn't about how to remove the alert but how to know where it comes from